# Can i use RX 570 graphics card on MSI MS 500 Psu

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply

I was thinking about buying RX 570 4gb but
I have cheap PSU MSI MS-500 that has 24 pin connector 1, 20 pin connector 1, SATA 2

Will this PSU support RX 570 4gb ?

I heard RX 570 requier 6 or 8 pin connector, and i wonder if i can connect it ?

BTW my motherboard supports RX 570.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I heard RX 570 require 6 or 8 pin connector, and I wonder if I can connect it ?

Your PSU doesn't have a single PCIe power connector.  So you will be unable to use an adapter on a 6-pin connector that doesn't exist.

> Will this PSU support RX 570 4gb ?

The AMD RX 570 will not function without a PCIe power connector.